# Efficiently loading collection array from csv with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, csv, pymongo

The csv file has several fields, but only two are of interest here: `ID` and `CODE`. There can be duplicates ( several rows with the same `ID` and `CODE` values. The objective is to get a collection like

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5001"),
"CODE" : [ code1 , code2 , code3 ],
"ID" : "10001"
 }
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5002"),
"CODE" : [ code3 ],
"ID" : "10002"
 }
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5003"),
"CODE" : [ code2 , code3 ],
"ID" : "10003"
 }
```

where the `CODE` arrays contain unique elements, and there are no duplicated `ID` documents.

The csv file is large ( `cut | sort | uniq` isn't an option ). My current approach is to create a dict `_u` of unique `ID` values, then create an indexed collection as such:

```
 for ID in _u:
     ID_obj = { "ID"   : ID , 
                "CODE" : [] }
     z = db.my_collection.insert( ID_obj )

 z = db.my_collection.ensure_index( "ID" , unique = True )
```

Then I iterate through the rows of the csv file making sure that the `CODE` array only keeps unique values:

```
 z = db.my_collection.update({ "ID" : ID } , {"$addToSet":{ "CODE" : csv_code_value }}, True )
```

What is the most efficient way to load the csv data into `my_collection`?

The csv data itself has 00's of columns, but the relevant structure is:

```
 ID,CODE,DESC,DATE
 10003,code2,second description,10/7/2010
 10001,code1,first description,10/1/2010
 10003,code3,third description,10/8/2010
 10003,code3,third description,10/9/2010
 10001,code1,first description,10/2/2010
 10001,code1,first description,10/3/2010
 10001,code2,second description,10/4/2010
 10002,code3,third description,10/6/2010
 10001,code3,third description,10/5/2010
```

Comment: Can you show the header line of the CSV? Actually, you don't need pymongo to do this. The most efficient way would be to reduce the CSV to the fields you need and use [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) on it. If you show the header line, I'll gladly provide you with an awk script which will handle even extremely large files efficiently.

Comment: I've added some data assuming that awk will work off the relevant columns. Thanks.